# Scroll page to element on mobile is not working but on desktop yes, preventDefault is a problem?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm doing a website for desktop and mobile as well, the menu works perfect on desktop but not working on mobile, because I want the smothly scroll to id I use this code:

I found out that event.preventDefault() block a function I turn it off and it transfers me to id, but the animation is disabled at this point

```
    $( 'a[href^="#"]' ).on( 'click', function ( event ) {
        var target = $( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
        var znacznik = $( $( this ).attr( 'a' ) );
        if ( target.length ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $( 'html, body' ).animate( {
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 80
            }, 1000 );
        }

    } );
```

Is there any way to make it works on android? Maybe another function then event.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: Are you using a button to scroll to the element? Like a button that takes you to the top of the page, or when you click on the element it scrolls you to that place?

Comment: Wordpress make a li link for me, i use in wordpress 
<div id="menu-glowne">
         <?php
  wp_nav_menu(array(
   'name' => 'Menu Główne'
  ));   
 ?>   
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be overthinking this one, put an href on the button you want to scroll to, like so:

```
<a href="#top"><button></button></a>
```

And for the smooth scrolling all I would do is set your CSS to the following:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Sets the entire page to have animations be smooth between elements.

Comment: It doesn't work witrh Safari and IE, looking for another solution.